# In Kotlin, how to make a property accessible by only specific type

Tags: android, kotlin

Lets say I have a Kotlin class similar to this:

```
class MyKotlinExample {
    val mMyString = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

`MutableLiveData` extends `LiveData` however I don't want to expose `MutableLiveData` to other classes. They should only see/access `LiveData<String>` as my special `String`

Is it possible, and/or good/advised etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties):

```
class MyKotlinExample {

    private val _myString = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val myString: LiveData<String>
      get() = _myString
}
```

---

You can also provide an interface to your clients, which provides only `LiveData<String>`. Given the following classes:

```
interface LiveData<T> {

    val value: T
}

data class MutableLiveData<T>(override var value: T) : LiveData<T>
```

Create the following interface/implementation:

```
interface MyExampleInterface {

    val myString: LiveData<String>
}

class MyExampleClass : MyExampleInterface {

    override val myString: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("")
}
```

Internally, you can access `myString` as `MutableLiveData`, and you can pass the instance of `MyExampleClass` as `MyExampleInterface` so they can only access `myString` as `LiveData<String>`.

Comment: I think this is the answer but it seems ugly.

Comment: thanks, second one seems a solid way. currently decided if it is an overkill.

I need to learn kotlin way of thinking :P

Comment: first upvote. This is the simplest way to do that.  And note private backing field has no getters/setters just same as java field.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a getter which does the cast for you:

```
class MyKotlinExample {
    private val mMyString = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getNonMutableLiveData(): LiveData<String> = mMyString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin creators heard our voice and provided a simple way of doing this on Kotlin 1.7 :

```
private val item = MutableLiveData<Item>()
    public get(): LiveData<Item>
```

or just:

```
val item = MutableLiveData <Item>()
    get(): LiveData <Item>
```

Note: It is currently subject to opt-in and have limited support, so we will have to wait for a bit longer for stable release.

Answer (score -1):

I would make the field `private` and expose the value like so:

```
class MyKotlinExample {
    private val mMyString = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getMyString(): String = mMyString.getValue()
}
```

Comment: this is currently how I do, is there a way to get rid of getter function?

Comment: Not really- you want to expose a value of one type as a different type, so you will need two different ways to access that value.

Answer (score -2):

This is quite simple - you set the type of the property to `LiveData<String>`, but initialize it with the instance of `MutableLiveData<String>`:

```
class MyKotlinExample {
    val mMyString: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

Comment: this way `MyKotlinExample` class is also blocked using methods from `MutableLiveData`